# AttributeError at /payment/ cards

Tags: python, django, view, stripe-payments

I'm trying to develop an e-commerce website. For some reason, I'm receiving this error, although cards seems to be attributed correctly.

My views.py:

```
@login_required
def PaymentView(request):

    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
        order = Order.objects.get(cart=cart)
    except:
        the_id = None
        return redirect(reverse("myshop-home"))

    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            user_stripe = request.user.userstripe.stripe_id
            customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(user_stripe)
        except:
            customer = None
            pass
        if customer is not None:
            token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')
            card = customer.cards.create(card=token)
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount= 400, 
                currency="usd",
                card= card,
                customer = customer,
                description = "Charge for %s" %(self.request.user.username)
            )
```

What actually is the problem here?

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: raise AttributeError(*err.args)
AttributeError: cards

Comment: That's not the traceback. You will find on the console where you run Django on.

Comment: card = customer.cards.create(card=token)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\stripe\stripe_object.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(*err.args)
AttributeError: cards

Comment: @Abrar you should edit the question to include that error message as a quote. It's not correct to post the error message as a comment separated from the question.

Answer (score 0):

In that line: card = customer.cards.create(card=token)
I think you wanted to create card instance.

To create object you have to do sth like that:
YourModel.objects.create(....)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects

Comment: No in that line I am creating credit card for the customer, which is associated with stripe

Comment: If your Card model has field: customer as a foreign key to model Customer, the way is: Card.objects.create(customer=customer). If in your card model there is a field for token, add it.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the Stripe docs, you can [create a Card for a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/create?lang=python) like this:

```
stripe.Customer.create_source(
  "cus_xxx",
  source="tok_yyy",
)
```